# Shortest distance between two points via calculus of variations

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, arc-length

This problem might be trivial but when solving it using calculus of variations it's not so stupid.

Suppose we have a fixed boundary condition $f(a) = f(b) = 0$ and we want to find the shortest distance between two points, so we choose $f$ to minimize the functional
$$
I(f) = \int_a^b \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2} dx
$$
we solved this in class and got $f'' = 0$ which is a straight line.  However, could we have just solved the problem
$$
\min I(f) = \int_a^b f'(x)^2 dx
$$
since it is a monotonic transformation of the original function?  I know this works in calculus but not sure about when dealing with functionals.  It gives me the same answer ($f'' = 0$) but is this just coincidental?  The second problem involves significantly less work. Thanks!

Comment: The first integral is the definition of arclength. So if you want to minimize length, you minimize the definition. I'm not sure what you did to get the second integral, but it's definitely not a length calculation, so it doesn't have the same meaning

Comment: I understand that it doesn't have the same units. I am trying to solve the first equation.  My question is simply whether or not the minimizer, $f$, will be the same in both problems.  For instance, in a simple calculus problem, the minimizer $x$ will be the same for $g(x)^2$ as it is for $\sqrt{1+g(x)^2}$.  I'm wondering if the same type of idea applies here

Comment: It will not, try the problem again with a non-trivial constraint. Take $f(a) = A$ and $f(b) = B$ such that $A \neq B$

Comment: Even then I get $f'' = 0$, so it is a straight line connecting $(a,A)$ and $(b,B)$ for both problems.

Comment: Here is a derivation using the Euler -Lagrange Equation: http://www.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~rac/MT5802/Calculus%20of%20variations.pdf

Comment: The formatting is pretty messed up on this...

Comment: Yeah, I know , I took screen shots of the document to get a good copy.

Comment: @Alan Does that document contain a proof of the claim in the OP's question? I can't really read it...

Comment: Technically it is pretty simplified, but it is understandable. I had a more complete exposition of finding the geodesics in the plane using the Euler-Lagrange Equation, setting  up the functional and solving it. Then proving it is a minimum using the second variation. Too much for this particular question. So I fell back on this simplified treatment, it seems to get the result without too  many complications. I'd say it's pretty good.

Comment: Okay , here's another reference: "The Calculus of Variations" by Bruce van Brunt
Link: http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Calculus_of_Variations.html?id=McBCbLDjXk0C
Example 2.2.1: Geodesics in the Plane , page 33, (and follow up in a later chapter)

Comment: @Alan But is it true that optimizing a monotonic transformation of the integration, results in the same answer as optimizing the original integrand? Can one always do such things (as squaring and subtracting one from the integrand like in the post) without changing the answer, and if so how does one prove that? I don't think the OP is asking about how the Euler-Lagrange equation works generally, they are asking about this specific issue.

Comment: @NotNotLogical Yes, I see. I was trying to backtrack over material that is pretty standard fare in differential geometry. Generally,  how does one set up two point boundary equations on  more general surfaces and solve the equations using a variational approach. I have a few examples , the straight line in the plane is one of them.

Comment: We have that in $\mathbb{R}$ the minimum for $(x^2, x^{2n},(x e^x)^{2n},\cdots )$ is the same. In functional/variational calculus, the problem is similar. There are infinite $f'(x)$ functionals that have the same minimizing function.

Comment: Not sure if this comment is appropriate here, but I've always found this proof to be a bit problematic. Doesn't the arclength formula depend on applying the Euclidean distance via Pythagoras' theorem? Isn't that implicitly assuming that a straight line is the shortest distance between two points? And wouldn't using that result to show the same be circular logic? I'm not talking about geodesics in general, I'm talking about how this calculus of variations problem of "proving" that a line segment is the shortest distance between two points on a Cartesian plane is almost always featured in texts

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the result is coincidental.

Consider minimization of the functional:
$$
I(f)=\int_a^b\sqrt{{f(x)}^2+{f'(x)}^2}\;dx.\tag1
$$

If I correctly understand your point, the alternative way in this case would be the minimization of
$$
I^*(f)=\int_a^b\left({f(x)}^2+{f'(x)}^2\right)\;dx.\tag2
$$
But these two functionals lead to completely different Euler-Lagrange equations:
$$\begin{align}
f(f^2+2f'^2-f''f)=0;\tag{1'}\\
f-f''=0,\tag{2'}
\end{align}$$
which have (except for the case $f(a)=f(b)=0$) completely different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the general functional

$$\int_a^b\Phi(f'(x))\,dx.$$

The Euler-Lagrange equations read

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac\partial{\partial f'}\Phi(f')=0$$

and

$$\frac{d}{dx}\Phi'(f')=f''\Phi''(f')=0.$$

Hence $f''(x)=0$ is always a solution, as is $f'(x)=\Phi''^{-1}(0)$, a constant.

Comment: Trying to understand. What is second solution for two cases that OP gives?

Comment: @Narasimham: I have not tried, but there is *a priori* no reason to get the same result. The "monotonic" argument does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment, not an answer, just to share my thoughts.

You mention that monotone transformations of functions yield equivalent optimization problems. This is true because, taking $g(x)$ to be monotone increasing so that $g'(x)>0$ for all $x$ in the domain, $$\frac{d}{dx}g(f(x))=g'(f(x))f'(x)=0\iff f'(x)=0$$ since $g'(x)$ is never zero.

But I simply cannot find a way to extend this argument to the case of variational problems. If we have a solution to the transformed problem with $g(f(x,y,y'))$ (in your case $g(t)=t^2-1$ and the domain is $t\ge 0$) then we know that $$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}g\big(f(x,y,y')\big)=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial }{\partial y'}g\big(f(x,y,y')\big)$$ which expands to $$g'(f)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=g''(f)\frac{df}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}+g'(f)\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}.$$ We want this to imply that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$$ so that we can conclude (under suitable conditions) that we have optimized the original problem. But I can find no way to realize that implication, given only that $g'(t)>0$.

Clearly the proof is done if we have $g''(t)\equiv 0$, that is, if $g$ is a *linear* function. Unfortunately yours is quadratic.

Comment: I mean the case of linearity makes sense because you can separate the integrals and then pull out the constant, making the transformation irrelevant.

Comment: @user148848 Good point. On another note, since the $g''$ term is giving the problem, I suppose a counter-example would have to involve non-trivial $g''$ (it is constant for the case of squaring). Pursuing something in that line might yield results.

Comment: Okay for a fact I've checked and for the multi-dimensional case (minimum surface area) these two results do not yield the same result.  For the one-dimensional case, you're probably right, you might need a more interesting g'' to get a counterexample.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is expected, not coincidental. That is how it should be as per calculus of variations concepts verifiable using Euler-Lagrange. The effect is the same in the two cases you mention. However the cause is different, it is not from monotonic changes from the functional. It is a class (or type) of functionals dealt with Euler-Lagrange through this EL uniform procedure. Let us see how.

Application of Euler-Lagrange on functionals

$$ \sqrt{1+ f^{'2}(x)}, f^{'2}(x),\dfrac{1- f^{'2}(x)}{\sin(1+ f^{'7}(x))},\;...$$

all lead to the very same solution viz., $ y'=$  a constant, the straight lines.

This happens due to the appearance of a *single derivative variable* $y'$ dependent *pure functional*.

For example when you take another  hypothetical

$$ \int y' (1- y^{'2})dx$$

after extremization the solution should be the same again, you can verify with EL Equn.

For that matter in general **any $f(y')$**  *pure functional (without x)* would lead to the same straight lines for a solution, viz., ***$ y^{'}=const,\;y^{''}=0.$***

I am supplying the proof here that ***any***  functional dependent purely on  $y'$ would lead to straight line solutions.

$$ L= \int f(y') dx  \tag1$$
Beltrami's formula when devoid of $x$ or its functions gives:

$$ f(y') -y'\cdot \dfrac{df(y')}{dy'}=C_1 \tag2 $$

(Full derivative as for single variable, $y$ terms treated constant when differentiating wrt $y'$).

For symbolic brevity let $u= y'$  operating as independent variable.

$$ f(u)-u\cdot\dfrac{d f(u)}{du}=C_1\tag3$$

$$\dfrac{df(u)}{f(u)-C_1}=\dfrac{du}{u} \tag4$$

Integrating,
$$ log [f(u)-C_1]= log \;u + log\;C_2 \tag5 $$

$$ f(u)= C_2 \;u +C_1\tag6 $$

$$ f(y')= C_2\; y'+ C_1\tag7 $$

Differentiating with respect to $x$

$$\dfrac{df(y')}{dx}= C_2\; y^{''} \tag8$$

The LHS should vanish as we began with the premise/assumption that $f'(u)$ does not involve (is independent of)  $x$ explicitly.

$$ y''=0 \rightarrow y= C_3 x + C_4 \tag9$$
are straight lines in the plane for all such functionals as a *class*.